# Outlook VBA 2013 Access Parent Folders

Tags: vba, outlook

Okay, I was reading a tutorial on how to access parent folders outside of the Inbox and noticed that it was using "Set". To my knowledge, this command is deprecated and seems so whenever I have tried to use it in my code.

http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2006/08/03/how-can-i-get-access-to-a-mail-folder-that-isn-t-a-subfolder-of-my-outlook-inbox.aspx

```
    ' Set Outlook parameters
    objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    iNameSpace = myOlApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")                       ' Set current NameSpace
    Dim oExp As Outlook.Explorer
    Dim oSel As Outlook.Selection
    oExp = objOutlook.ActiveExplorer
    oSel = oExp.Selection
    Dim strFolderName As Object
    Dim objInbox As Outlook.Folder
    Dim objMailbox As Outlook.Folder
    Dim objFolder As Outlook.Folder


    Const olFolderInbox = 6
    objInbox = iNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
    strFolderName = objInbox.Folders.Parent()
    objMailbox = iNameSpace.Folders(strFolderName)
    objFolder = objMailbox.Folders("Europe")
```

When trying the code above, I get a type error: Additional information: Type mismatch, on this line:

```
    objMailbox = iNameSpace.Folders(strFolderName)
```

When I change this to an "Object", I get the same error.

Any Idea what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access the parent of the Inbox folder, try `iNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Parent`

To access a folder on the same level as the Inbox, try `iNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Parent.Folders.Item("The Folder name")`

Comment: Thank!
This finally worked.
`Const olFolderInbox = 6
        objMailbox = iNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Parent()
        objFolder = objMailbox.Folders.Item("Europe")`

Answer (score 0):

The following code will not work.

```
 strFolderName = objInbox.Folders.Parent()
```

The [Folders](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff860950.aspx) collection does't provide the Parent method.

```
 objMailbox = iNameSpace.Folders(strFolderName)
```

The [Folders](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff864011.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) property doesn't accept an object arguments.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Again, I tried the Outlook.Folder type and received the same error. I just tried the Object type as I couldn't think of anything else. 
I just need to get access to the Parent of inbox, so I can get a folder on the same level as the inbox.

Comment: objInbox.Parent.Folders("Any folder name")